# Why Quartz is not writing into mysql default quartz tables?

Tags: spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I’m using spring boot 2 and quartz, flyway for table creations. When i schedule job there in nothing into db. Any ideas? My quartz config is in configuration app. Can someone shere correct yml quartz config file.

Regards

Comment: Have you set spring.quartz.job-store-type=jdbc and spring.quartz.jdbc.initialize-schema=always ?

Comment: You should check official documentation at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-quartz.html

Answer (score 1):

Configure Quartz with springboot application.

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
org.quartz.scheduler.makeSchedulerThreadDaemon = true
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.makeThreadsDaemons = true
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount: 20
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority: 5
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX 
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = false
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myDs
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 25000


# Configure Datasources
```

Refer This Demo.

https://www.opencodez.com/java/quartz-scheduler-with-spring-boot.htm
https://github.com/davidkiss/spring-boot-quartz-demo

Answer (score 1):

If you are using spring boot 2.1 then add in your application.properties files as follows

```
spring.quartz.jdbc.initialize-schema=ALWAYS
spring.quartz.jdbc.schema=classpath:tables_postgres.sql
```

the tables are created automatically

Thanks

references:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.M1/reference/html/boot-features-quartz.html